# Where is WithMaxRetry and WithShouldRetry in dotnet graph SDK v5

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

In version 4 of the Microsoft Graph SDK (dotnet) you had the ability to use the fluent methods `.WithShouldRetry` and `.WithMaxRetry`. See in example this [blogpost](https://www.locktar.nl/programming/how-to-use-withshouldretry-of-the-microsoft-graph-graphserviceclient/).

I'm now upgrading my application to v5 of the SDK and because of the [removal of `.Request()`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#removal-of-request-from-the-fluent-api) it's not possible to set the retry anymore.

How can we implement the retry in SDK v5?

**Update:**
See new [blogpost for v5 of the SDK](https://www.locktar.nl/programming/how-to-use-retry-functionality-in-microsoft-graph-net-sdk-v5/).

Comment: I would suggest to create new issue: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues. I didn't find any info how to set retry policy.

Comment: @user2250152 see my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75720940/801005) for detailed approach to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The retryhandler is now a IRequestOption in Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.Middleware.Options so you can do something like

```
    using Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.Middleware.Options;

    private static Event CreateEvent(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, string emailAddress)
    {
        var requestBody = new Event
        {
            Subject = "Let's go for lunch",
            Body = new ItemBody
            {
                ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                Content = "Does mid month work for you?",
            },
            Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
            {
                DateTime = "2023-03-15T12:00:00",
                TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time",
            },
            End = new DateTimeTimeZone
            {
                DateTime = "2023-03-15T14:00:00",
                TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time",
            },
            Location = new Location
            {
                DisplayName = "Harry's Bar",
            },
            TransactionId = "7E163156-7762-4BEB-A1C6-729EA81755A7",
        };
        RetryHandlerOption retryHandlerOption = new RetryHandlerOption()
        {
            MaxRetry = 5
        };           
        var requestOptions = new List<IRequestOption>
        {                
            retryHandlerOption,
        };
        return graphServiceClient.Users[emailAddress].Calendar.Events.PostAsync(requestBody, rc => rc.Options = requestOptions).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for. Will update my original blogpost and see my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75720940/801005).

Answer (score 1):

@Glen Scales pointed me in the right direction. Here a more simple example with custom retry functionality.

```
// using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;
// using Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.Middleware.Options;

// Use random Guid for user that doesn't exist to force retry
string userId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

const int MaxRetry = 5; // So number of call are MaxRetry + 1 (1 is the original call)

RetryHandlerOption retryHandlerOption = new RetryHandlerOption()
{
    MaxRetry = MaxRetry,
    ShouldRetry = (delay, attempt, httpResponse) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Request returned status code {httpResponse.StatusCode}");

        // Add more status codes here or change your if statement...
        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            return false;

        double delayInSeconds = CalculateDelay(httpResponse, attempt, delay);

        if (attempt == 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"Request failed, let's retry after a delay of {delayInSeconds} seconds");
        else if (attempt == MaxRetry)
            Console.WriteLine($"This was the last retry attempt {attempt}");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"This was retry attempt {attempt}, let's retry after a delay of {delayInSeconds} seconds");

        return true;
    }
};

var requestOptions = new List<IRequestOption>
{
    retryHandlerOption,
};

User? user = await graphClient
    .Users[userId]
    .GetAsync(requestConfiguration => requestConfiguration.Options = requestOptions);

/// <summary>
/// This is reverse engineered from:
/// https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/blob/dev2/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/Middleware/RetryHandler.cs#L164
/// </summary>
/// <param name="response"></param>
/// <param name="retryCount"></param>
/// <param name="delay"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static double CalculateDelay(HttpResponseMessage response, int retryCount, int delay)
{
    HttpHeaders headers = response.Headers;
    double delayInSeconds = delay;
    if (headers.TryGetValues(RetryAfter, out var values))
    {
        var retryAfter = values.First();
        if (int.TryParse(retryAfter, out var delaySeconds))
        {
            delayInSeconds = delaySeconds;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var mPow = Math.Pow(2, retryCount);
        delayInSeconds = mPow * delay;
    }

    const int
        MaxDelay = 180; // From github code https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/blob/2e43863e349b4b3ebe2e166c26e3afcc4a974365/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/Middleware/Options/RetryHandlerOption.cs#L18
    delayInSeconds = Math.Min(delayInSeconds, MaxDelay);

    return delayInSeconds;
}
```

Comment: Created a new [blogpost for v5](https://www.locktar.nl/programming/how-to-use-retry-functionality-in-microsoft-graph-net-sdk-v5/)

Comment: How is delayInSeconds taken into account in subsequent retries?

Comment: I updated my blogpost and this answer with the Calculate function. Forgot to put that in place.
See summary for original code.

Comment: Thanks, found that from your blog already, but to me it looks like you just set delayInSeconds value. How does the retry logic know to delay as you're not doing anything with the delayInSeconds value?

Comment: I had to think as well because it's been a while. But I debugged my sample app and it works. The handler of Microsoft is in control. That handler is doing the retry (always!). Look at the `RetryHandlerOption` of Kiota. The sample above is setting the RetryHandlerOption as a IRequestOption for the call. So, you only implementing the max number of retries (`MaxRetry`) and IF it should retry. So, in example on which `httpResponse.StatusCode`. The delay param is always 3 but I wanted to log the number of retries and the delay. That's why I created my own Calc function. Input is 3, out 3, 6, 12, 24

Comment: The screenshot of my blogpost is correct.
It works well and just tested it again. The `delayInSeconds` is just for logging purposes! 
The ShouldRetry property is just to determine IF it should retry.